# Unable to view Browse Files&Upload Files buttons to upload Product Images in Tablets(Android OS)

Tags: magento-1.9.2.1

I am able to upload images when using a lappy or desktop. But when I try the same in an Android Tablet, I am unable to see the Browse Files and the Upload Files Buttons. It gives a message to install Flash Player. But it doesn't work.

Did anyone come across this issue? Or if there is any possible solution, please post it.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For uploading images you have to flash player in your device.

Eaither you install flash player or upgarde your magento to `1.9.3.0`

From `Magento 1.9.3.0` onwards for uploading product image you wont require flash player.

You can install flash player for your android device from here.

http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/adobe/adobe-flash-player-11-1/adobe-flash-player-11-1-11-1-115-81-release/adobe-flash-player-11-1-11-1-115-81-android-apk-download/